# `openssl`: Subject Alternative Name

Tags: bash, ssl, openssl, https, certificates

I wrote this bit of code to get the Common Name of the *subject* field in the SSL certificate for a given domain:

```
$ echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\nEOT" | \
   openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>&1 | \
   grep subject
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
```

However, this only gives me the “subject” value. Alternative CNs may be listed in the “Subject Alternative Name” field. For example:

[image]

So, how can I get the value of the Subject Alternative Name field in Bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might not work under every circumstance, but try

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>&1 | openssl x509 -text | grep DNS
```

Comment: Thanks so much! `openssl x509 -text` is what I was looking for. I guess I was Googling for the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 3):

What @stuart-p-bentley wrote got me thinking and I came up with this way of getting a comma delimited list of "Subject Alternative Names" using `openssl`, `awk` and `tr`. The sed line in his answer does not work on FreeBSD per example.

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>&1 | openssl x509 -text | awk '/X509v3 Subject Alternative Name/ {getline;gsub(/ /, "", $0); print}' | tr -d "DNS:"
```

Here is what you get with google.com

```
*.google.com,*.android.com,*.appengine.google.com,*.cloud.google.com,*.google-analytics.com,*.google.ca,*.google.cl,*.google.co.in,*.google.co.jp,*.google.co.uk,*.google.com.ar,*.google.com.au,*.google.com.br,*.google.com.co,*.google.com.mx,*.google.com.tr,*.google.com.vn,*.google.de,*.google.es,*.google.fr,*.google.hu,*.google.it,*.google.nl,*.google.pl,*.google.pt,*.googleadapis.com,*.googleapis.cn,*.googlecommerce.com,*.googlevideo.com,*.gstatic.cn,*.gstatic.com,*.gvt1.com,*.gvt2.com,*.urchin.com,*.url.google.com,*.youtube-nocookie.com,*.youtube.com,*.youtubeeducation.com,*.ytimg.com,android.com,g.co,goo.gl,google-analytics.com,google.com,googlecommerce.com,urchin.com,youtu.be,youtube.com,youtubeeducation.com
```

Comment: `tr -d "DNS:"` is *not* a good solution to get all the domains in the SAN, as the SAN field may contain other kinds of values than DNS, such as IP addresses. I don't know how you'd do it with awk, but `sed -nr '/^ {12}X509v3 Subject Alternative Name/{n; s/(^|,) *DNS:/,/g; s/(^|,) [^,]*//gp}'` is how I did it with sed [here](https://github.com/plushu/plushu-nginx-app-vhosts/blob/master/hooks/vhost-app#L16).

Comment: The equivalent awk translation would probably be `awk '/^ {12}X509v3 Subject Alternative Name/ {getline; gsub(/(^|,) *DNS:/, ",", $0); gsub(/(^|,) [^,]*/, "", $0); print}'`, though I don't know why that would be any better than using sed (I can't see why the sed wouldn't work on FreeBSD, unless you need to use `-nE` instead of `-nr` due to being on an old version).

Comment: Another reason `tr -d "DNS:"` is not a good solution is because `tr -d` deletes *sets of characters*, not strings. You might as well do `tr -d ":A-Z"`. (While you're at it, throw out the `gsub(/ /, "", $0);` and add spaces to the set for deletion. Or just do all your deletion in the `awk` command in the first place, where you can do it with strings and patterns - at which point you reach my previous comment's code.)

Comment: (The code referenced at the end of [my first comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67203/openssl-subject-alternative-name/149188#comment265588_156805) has moved to https://github.com/plushu/plushu-app-nginx-servers/blob/master/hooks/vhost-app/25_write-app-conf#L16 .)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that *will* work in every circumstance (and strips leading space):

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>&1 | openssl x509 -text |
  sed -nr '/^ {12}X509v3 Subject Alternative Name/{n;s/^ *//p}'
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of issues this works around (that the other answer doesn’t)? Thanks!

Comment: Unlike the other answer, this doesn't inadvertently include other fields that contain "DNS" (such as what you could encounter running the other answer for the certificate of a service that provides DNS).

Answer (score 0):

Also use the switch

```
-certopt no_pubkey,no_sigdump,no_validity,no_serial,no_header,no_issuer,no_version,no_aux,no_signame,no_subject
```